# how get context react using django

Tags: python, django, reactjs

i need get context in react using django 
but i cant do it

this is my code
in my jsx

```
<h1>{{titulo}}</h1>
<h2>{{ejemplo}}</h2>
```

in my template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body >
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bundle.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in my view py:

```
def registro (request,giro):
    reg = 'Registro Normal'
    if giro==1:
        reg='Registro Especial'

    context = {
        'ejemplo':'tests',
        'titulo':reg
    }
    return render(request,'home/registro.html',context)
```

but does not render and wild error appeared :(

Uncaught ReferenceError: titulo is not defined

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Django context is only when the template is rendered *on the server*. React uses Javascript which means it's rendered *on the browser*. If you want to use Django variables in your React app, you will need to set those variables in Javascript (making sure to do so before `bundle.js` is imported).

So your template might look something like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body >
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /* Put your context vars here. I recommend putting them under 
     a variable to avoid naming conflicts. 
  */
  var context = {
    titulo: '{{titulo}}',
    ejemplo: '{{ejemplo}}'
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bundle.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in React you can reference `context.variable` to get the value you need.

Comment: Cant you just say `var context = {{context}}` and get everything at once?

Comment: @West That could be an option, though I think Django adds some extra data to the context. If you go that route you may want to embed all your data under a specific context key. I think you'd also need to do `json.dumps()` in your view so that you can render the full context object.