# Using React with Django, do I need react-router?

Tags: django, reactjs, react-router

Suppose I have an existing Django webapp with a bunch of urls in urls.py. Now suppose I want to add a number of webpages to this Django app, where the new webpages are built using React.

From what I understand, React has its own routing capability (in react-router) so that if I go to `mydomain.com/page1/` it will serve one thing and if I go to `mydomain.com/page2/` it will serve something else.

But what if I don't want to use react-router? In other words, if I have say 10 new pages to add and each page will have its own URL, then why can't I just set this up in Django's urls.py file?

Currently in `urls.py` I have a url defined like this:

```
url(r'^testview/', views.testview),
```

In `views.py` I define testview like this:

```
def testview(request):
    return render(request, 'testview.html', {})
```

My Django templates are stored in a folder `BASE_DIR/myproject/templates/` and I set the TEMPLATES variable inside `BASE_DIR/myproject/settings.py` so Django knows where to find the templates. 
So in my view method above, `testview.html` refers to `BASE_DIR/myproject/templates/testview.html`. The contents of that file are:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

{% block main %}
<div id="App1"></div>
{% render_bundle 'vendors' %}
{% render_bundle 'App1' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, I defined `App1` in `App1.jsx` as follows:

```
import React from "react"

import Headline from "../components/Headline"

    class App1 extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <Headline>Hello There!</Headline>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

This works fine, but what if I wanted to have 10 different pages? Would I need new app files like `App2.jsx`, `App3.jsx`, etc, one for each page?

Finally, suppose I want to pass a Django variable to my React app, for example:

```
def testview_with_time(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'testviewtime.html', {
        'currtime': '%s' % str(now),
    })
```

Here I pass the variable `currtime`. How do I pass this into the React `App1` class?

Answer (score 2):

@Marc, I think you are on the right track with what's been given to you.
I agree with @SrThompson's answer, but I'd make some slight changes:

---

**Starting with Django**. In your `testview.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

{% block main %}
<div id="{{component_name}}"></div>
{% render_bundle 'vendors' %}
{% render_bundle component_name %}
{% endblock %}
```

So, there would be a `component_name` context variable that defines the component being rendered by react and also sets the ID of the main `div`.

---

**Jumping to React**, you could have a `render.js` file that would be like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../somewhere';    

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App>
      <Component />
    </App>,
    document.getElementById(Component.name)
  )
}

export default render;
```

This render function takes the `Component` you passed as a parameter and renders it to the element with `id='Component'`, just like you set in the context variable in Django. You also get the `App` component on top of every rendered component, just as a normal react app would work. Just call them using `render(App1.jsx)` for instance.

---

This way you would have to worry about creating only a single .hmtl file for rendering the react components.

Answer (score 1):

`react-router` is a Frontend router meant to be used on Single Page Applications. If you're not building a SPA you don't need it.

You can hook up a react parent component anywhere you want, it's pretty flexible that way, but yes, if you want to go the server-side rendering way with your Django views and use react to enhance parts of it, then yes, you would need `App2.jsx`, `App3.jsx`, etc. (I would suggest picking better names though)

Also, if you're going this way, don't use react to build the full page, only use it where you need the extra interactivity, like a widget or something. If you're rendering the entire page in react without making the app a SPA you lose the benefits from both the JS client app and server-side rendering

You can't pass variables from django views to react components, because they're rendered on the browser. Whatever data you need in your react components has to be fetched with an `AJAX` request, just like any other JS library

Comment: Just an idea, about passing the context variables, there is this answer worth taking a look at which provides a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43457082/1455838

Comment: That could definitely work, although it's a bit too hacky for my taste. If it's the solution OP wants though, then great. Good contribution either way

Comment: I agree this looks a bit hacky. Mainly because, while you are inside some App.jsx, the context variables just seem to apear out of nowhere! XD. But he could just call it 'convention' and move on. Hehe.

Comment: "Convention". I love it. That's job safety right there hahaha